# Logical replication from Posgres on Windows to Postgres in docker container on Linux

Tags: postgresql, docker, replication

I'm using the bitnami/postgresql:latest image and I'm able to connect from a Win32 program (Delphi using the Unidac drivers) to PostgreSQL database running on Ubuntu server in a docker container.

The users will use a Win32 program to capture field survey data offline and then they, going online, want to replicate the data to the PostgreSQL database on Ubuntu server.

It seems to me I should use logical replication because a user may work with only a subset of the total master database on the Ubuntu server.

I must be able to do a mapping of the postgresql.conf and the pg_hba.conf files.
The part of my docker-compose.yml file to run PostgreSQL in a docker container:

```
  postgres:
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: postgres
    image: bitnami/postgresql:latest
    environment:
      - TZ="Africa/Johannesburg"
      - POSTGRES_DATABASE=sdb_risk
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
      - 5433:5433
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data:/bitnami/postgresql
#      - .pg_hba.conf:/bitnami/postgresql/conf/pg_hba.conf

#      - .postgresql.conf:/bitnami/postgresql/conf/postgresql.conf 
networks:
  - dreamfactory-tier
  - app-tier
```

My question is: Am I on the right track to do a logical replication and if so, how do I map the pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf files?

Regards,

Nols Smit

Answer (score 1):

Logical replication does work for Postgres running in a docker container. What I did to figure it out:

I figured it out by running Postgres on the host: Ubuntu Server (not in a docker container).
Make a copy of your postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files
Copy your postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files to your docker root folder (where you have your docker-compose.yml) file

**The changes in my postgresql file:**

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WRITE-AHEAD LOG
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Settings -

################# wal_level originally commented out ... Nols Smit #########
wal_level = logical         # minimal, replica, or logical
############################################################################
```

**The changes in my pg_hba.conf file:**

```
host all all all md5
################## New entry below   ... Nols Smit ##########################
host    all            all              0.0.0.0/0               md5   
host    starsdb        replicator       i7Laptop                md5
#############################################################################
```

Where starsdb is my Postgres database on the subscriber and i7Laptop the host name of the publisher

Remember that initially the subscriber database must be empty and also use uuids for primary keys for your tables.

Regards,

Nols Smit